# Can I add items to a slice in the creation statement depending on a condition?

Tags: go, slice, composite-literals

I have function that creates a slice like this :

```
func buildOptions(cfg *ServerConfig) []SomeType {

    return []SomeType{
        Option1,
        Option2,
        Option3,
    }
}
```

I need Option3 to be added to the slice only if a certain condition is met. Can it be done with some kind of immediate if in the same statement?

of do I have to do something like this:

```
func buildOptions(cfg *ServerConfig) []SomeType {

    options:= []SomeType{
        Option1,
        Option2,
    }

    if addOption3==true{
       options = append(options, Option3)
    }
    return options
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it in the initialisation expression. `append` is the way to do it.

Comment: *"Can it be done with some kind of immediate if in the same statement ?"* No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't have conditional inclusion of listed elements in a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

And it may be more verbose using an additional `if` and `append()`, but it's much more obvious what happens (what your code does).

You could achieve something like this using a helper function passing the condition and all the elements, but that just obfuscates the code more and would have worse performance.

Comment: @FunkSoulBrother One could argue about that. Why list a value which you don't want to add? That's obfuscation. Go aims simplicity. Add all kinds of features some find useful, and you'll end up with what Java is today.